# Woocommerce add or hide shipping method based on category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to remove or add some shipping options depending on the category of product that is in cart. For example: I have one product from category X and I want to add shipping-method-X to cart. And if I have one product from category X and one from another category, then shipping-method-X is disabled.
Function below checks if array contains category with ID=49 and if there is another category, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens in cart :( Please help

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_based_on_tag' ,    10, 1 );

function check_cart_for_share() {

global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;

$found = false;

  foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );

        $tmp = array();

        foreach ($terms as $term) {

            array_push($tmp, $term->term_id); 
        }
        array_unique($tmp);

        if (sizeof($tmp) > 1 AND in_array('49', $tmp)) {

        $found = true;
  }
}

return $found;

}

function hide_shipping_based_on_tag( $available_methods ) {

// use the function above to check the cart for the categories.
if ( check_cart_for_share() ) {

    // remove the method you want
    unset( $available_methods['flat_rate'] );
}

// return the available methods without the one you unset.
return $available_methods;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely your product is only in a single category with the ID of 49 which makes your if statement invalid. You should check for 0 or more entries.

```
if (sizeof($tmp) > 0 && in_array('49', $tmp)) {  \\... it is in the array
```